# boost mpl integral type accumulate

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

How do I add the numbers?

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<
    boost::mpl::int_<1>, boost::mpl::int_<2>,
    boost::mpl::int_<3>, boost::mpl::int_<4>,
    boost::mpl::int_<5>, boost::mpl::int_<6> > ints;
typedef boost::mpl::accumulate<ints, boost::mpl::int_<0>, ????? >::type sum;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** I was wrong, you can use `mpl::plus` directly, using the [placeholder expressions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/placeholder-expression.html). This simplifies the whole notation:

```
typedef mpl::accumulate<ints, mpl::int_<0>, mpl::plus<mpl::_1, mpl::_2>  >::type sum;
```

Of course it is also possible to obtain the same effect using a [metafunction class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunction-class.html) (which for adding is an overkill, but for something more complex might be reasonable):

```
struct plus_mpl
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    struct apply
    {
       typedef typename mpl::plus<T1,T2>::type type;
    };
};

typedef mpl::accumulate<ints, mpl::int_<0>, plus_mpl >::type sum;
```